# Trouble selecting a hidden menu item using SeleniumBasic for vba

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having some trouble selecting a hidden menu item on a work webpage using [SeleniumBasic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) for vba. I have tried to use `WebDriver.Mouse.MouseTo` to hover over each menu option so that I can select the object nested "beneath" it, but after the first hover the object cannot be found.

In the picture below I intend to navigate like this:

```
Pricing Admin
    System Admin
        Multi-PAG Upload
```

[image: picture]

To do this, I have to hover over **Pricing Admin** and subsequently hover over **System Admin** so that menu appears to click on **Multi-PAG Upload**. I have successfully gotten the driver to hover over **Pricing Admin** which brings up first menu list with three items ending in **System Admin**. However, trying to `FindElement()` for **System Admin** so that I can hover on it has proven very difficult.

I tend get an `object required` error or an `XPath selector invalid` depending on the method that I attempt. I start having problems at `Set systemAdmin =`.

Any advice would be welcome!

```
Public Sub SeleniumTest()

    Dim driver As New WebDriver

    'open chrome to site
    driver.start "chrome"
    driver.Get "http://www.website.net"

    'login
    driver.FindElementByName("j_username").SendKeys ("user")
    driver.FindElementByName("j_password").SendKeys ("pass")
    driver.FindElementById("submit_button").Click


    'hover over Pricing Admin
    Dim pricingAdmin As WebElement
    Set pricingAdmin = driver.FindElementById("prcngAdmMnuFrm:prcngAdmMnu")

    driver.Mouse.MoveTo pricingAdmin


    Dim systemAdmin As WebElement
    'neither selection method below works properly
'   Set systemAdmin = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'System Admin')]")
'   Set systemAdmin = driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='prcngAdmMnuFrm:prcngAdmMnu']/div/div/ul/li/ul/li[3]/ul/li[4]/a/span/span")

    driver.Mouse.MoveTo systemAdmin


    Dim multiPagUpload As WebElement
'   Set multiPagUpload = driver.FindElement("??")

    multiPagUpload.Click


    'closes browser window
    driver.Quit

End Sub
```

Here is the (abridged) HTML for the site. I trimmed out a bit of the lists for simplicity's sake but if it's actually necessary (for using javascript, etc) let me know and I can pop more in.

```
<div id="prcngAdmMnuFrm:prcngAdmMnu" style="">
    <div class="ui-widget ui-widget-content wijmo-wijmenu ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix wijmo-wijmenu-horizontal" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" role="menubar">
        <div class="scrollcontainer checkablesupport">
            <ul style="display: block;" class="wijmo-wijmenu-list ui-helper-reset" tabindex="0">
                <li role="menuitem" class="ui-widget wijmo-wijmenu-item ui-state-default ui-corner-all wijmo-wijmenu-parent" aria-haspopup="true" style="">
                    <a href="#" class="wijmo-wijmenu-link ui-corner-all" id="">
                        <span class="wijmo-wijmenu-text">
                            <span class="wijmo-wijmenu-text">Pricing Admin</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="wijmo-wijmenu-list ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix wijmo-wijmenu-child" style="display: none; left: 0px; top: 38px; position: absolute; list-style-type: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                        <li role="menuitem" class="ui-widget wijmo-wijmenu-item ui-state-default ui-corner-all wijmo-wijmenu-parent" aria-haspopup="true" style="">
                            <a href="#" class="wijmo-wijmenu-link ui-corner-all ui-state-focus">
                                <span class="wijmo-wijmenu-text">
                                    <span class="wijmo-wijmenu-text">System Admin</span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="wijmo-wijmenu-list ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix wijmo-wijmenu-child" style="display: none; left: 215px; top: -1px; position: absolute; list-style-type: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                                <li role="menuitem" class="ui-widget wijmo-wijmenu-item ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                                    <a onclick="showProcessingMessage('Loading');;var self = this; setTimeout(function() { var f = function(opt){ice.ace.ab(ice.ace.extendAjaxArgs({&quot;source&quot;:&quot;prcngAdmMnuFrm:menu_pad_sa_multi&quot;,&quot;execute&quot;:'@all',&quot;render&quot;:'@all',&quot;event&quot;:&quot;activate&quot;}, opt));}; f({node:self});}, 10);" style="cursor:pointer;" class="wijmo-wijmenu-link ui-corner-all">
                                        <span class="wijmo-wijmenu-text">
                                            <span class="wijmo-wijmenu-text">Multi-PAG Upload</span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var widget_prcngAdmMnuFrm_prcngAdmMnu = ice.ace.create("Menubar", ["prcngAdmMnuFrm:prcngAdmMnu", {
            "autoSubmenuDisplay": true,
            "direction": "auto",
            "animation": {
                "animated": "fade",
                "duration": 400
            }
        }]);
    </script>
</div>
```

If I've left anything out that you need to troubleshoot, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xpath which is used in the code is not correct. my suggesting to find the anchor element and move the mouse over.

**# System Admin Menu**

```
'Hover over Pricing Admin
Dim systemAdmin As WebElement
Set systemAdmin = driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[.//span[contains(.,'System Admin')]]")

driver.Mouse.MoveTo pricingAdmin
```

If the mouse hover does not work, we can still try to handle the menu by clicking on the anchor element and then sendkeys (keys.Arrow_Right)

**#Multi-PAG Upload**

```
Dim multiPagUpload As WebElement
Set multiPagUpload = driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[.//span[contains(.,'Multi-PAG Upload')]]")

multiPagUpload.Click
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get `Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method` on the line `Set systemAdmin =`

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 sounds like a VBA issue. lets try directly use the element than assigning to a variable. driver.Mouse.MoveTo driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[.//span[contains(.,'System Admin')]]")

Comment: Updated the code to remove duplicate "driver.driver". give it a try now

Comment: Oh gosh, I can't believe I didn't proof it well enough to notice the extra `driver.` >_>

Comment: sorry, quick followup question - is it possible to adjust the selection for **multiPagUpload** to click specifically on the text link and not just another part of the `<span>`?

Comment: The above xpath will click on the anchor part of the element,not the span. It identifies the anchor based on the text present on the child span element though.